Andrew Ng ML course using MATLAB?
Nowadays python is mostly used for machine learning and i think it is also used in new ML courses of Andrew Ng
https://www.quora.com/Why-was-MATLAB-not-used-in-the-Andrew-Ng-course-of-deep-learning
But I came across above link and being electrical engineer i was greatly surprised to know that MATLAB/Octave was used for first ML course of Andrew Ng, because i think generally an electrical engineer feels relatively more comfortable with MATLAB compared to python
(I tried to find relevant material on YouTube, but couldn't succeed)
can someone please share YouTube link of that MATLAB course?
Thanks

The original MATLAB course (with assignments) was put on Coursera, but the general lectures covering the topics can be found on YouTube. This is the link to the first lecture.

The MATLAB course is older. If you google around, you can find Python versions of the course content on github
